# Can I work remotely in Australia for 2 months per year?

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, australia, digital-nomads

I have a UK employer and wish to work remotely (which is possible, I work from home often) while in Australia for 2-3 months per year.  Technically this is not long enough to be considered living in Australia so I'm interested in how I would go about this legally.  It's worth noting that as a New Zealand citizen (I'm a dual national) it's rather easy for me to get a visa to be able to work in Australia, so that's not a problem.  It's more a concern regarding taxation and whether a UK company can pay me to carry out the work I normally carry out from home in the UK, but while I'm actually in Australia for two months (with the company being aware of this and wanting to ensure we do this legally).

Comment: Doesn't sound like a travel problem so much as something that [expatriates.se] might handle. Try asking there.

Comment: Useful to know thanks - so did you go via a visitor visa?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone curious, I discovered that Australia and UK have a Double Taxation Treaty that allows for this kind of thing so long as you're only staying less than 183 days for a calendar year and/or tax year.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/australia-tax-treaties

There are a few exceptions here and there, but article 14 (details 1 and 2 combined under that article) seem to exempt me from Australian taxation if I'm there less than 183 days so 2-3 months should be easy.

Comment: But you still need to declare your income in the UK, and will probably have to pay UK tax instead of Australian tax.